# Problem in log out user using Keycloack in React js app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, keycloak, react-context

I'm implementing authentication using [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) in React js app.

I'm using [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to manage the global states in this case are the `keycloackValue` and `authenticated` in `KeycloackContext`.

##### Cases:

1. When the app is running the first time, the app checks for `keycloackValue` and `authenticated`. The initial state for them are `null` and `false`.
2. If `keycloackValue` and `authenticated` are `null` and `false`, the app would initialize the keycloak login page (by calling `keycloak.init` in `KeycloackContext`).
3. If  `keycloackValue` and `authenticated` are `not null` and `true` (means that the user is successfully login through keycloak), then the app will render all components in `MyApp.js`.
4. If the user clicks the `log out button` in `Header` component, the app would set `keycloackValue` and `authenticated` into `null` and `false` also call the keycloak to log out the user. After that, the keycloak login page is called.

##### Problem:

I successfully logged in using keycloak. Then the app successfully rendered all components in `MyApp.js`.

The problem is when I clicked the `log out button` in `Header.js`, the `keycloackValue` and `authenticated` were successfully set to `null` and `false` also the keycloak successfully logged out. Then the app refreshed itself and rendered all components in `MyApp.js` (the app didn't call the keycloak login page).

##### Code:

index.js

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import MyApp from './my/App'
import { KeycloackContextProvider } from "./my/contexts/KeycloackContext"
 
ReactDOM.render(
    <KeycloackContextProvider>
        <MyApp/>
    </KeycloackContextProvider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

KeycloackContext.js

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'

// KEYCLOACK
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js'

const KeycloackContext = createContext()

const KeycloackContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [ keycloackValue, setKeycloackValue ] = useState(null)
    const [ authenticated, setAuthenticated ] = useState(false)

    const setKeycloack = () => {
        const keycloak = Keycloak({
            realm: process.env.REACT_APP_WULING_KEYCLOAK_REALM,
            url: process.env.REACT_APP_WULING_KEYCLOAK_URL,
            clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_WULING_KEYCLOAK_CLIENTID,
        })

        keycloak.init({
            onLoad: 'login-required', 
            checkLoginIframe: false,
        }).then(authenticated => {
            setKeycloackValue(keycloak)
            setAuthenticated(authenticated)
        })
    }

    const logout = () => {
        setKeycloack(null)
        setAuthenticated(false)
        keycloackValue.logout()
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setKeycloack()
    }, [])

    return (
        <KeycloackContext.Provider
            value={{
                keycloackValue,
                authenticated,
                logout
            }}
        >
            {props['children']}
        </KeycloackContext.Provider>
    )
}

export { KeycloackContextProvider, KeycloackContext }
```

MyApp.js

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

import Header from './components/Header/Header'
import Tab from './components/Tab/Tab'

// CONTEXTS
import { KeycloackContext } from './contexts/KeycloackContext'

import Device from './pages/Device/Device'
import Stock from './pages/Stock/Stock'

const MyApp = () => {
    const { keycloackValue, authenticated } = useContext(KeycloackContext)

    return (
        (keycloackValue && authenticated) &&
        <div className='app-root'>
            <Router>
                <Header/>
                <Tab/>

                <Redirect from='/' to='/device'/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/device'>
                        <Device/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path='/stock'>
                        <Stock/>
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MyApp
```

Header.js

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react'

// CONTEXTS
import { KeycloackContext } from '../../contexts/KeycloackContext'

const Header = () => {
    const { logout } = useContext(KeycloackContext)

    return (
        <div className='logout-popup-root'>
            <p className='logout-popup-username'>Username</p>
            <p className='logout-popup-email'>username@gmail.com</p>
            <div className='logout-popup-divider'></div>
            <div 
                className='logout-popup-logout-button'
                onClick={() => logout()}
            >
                Log Out
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header
```

Related dependencies:

```json
"keycloak-js": "^15.0.0",
"react": "16.12.0",
"react-dom": "16.12.0",
"react-router-dom": "5.1.2",
"react-scripts": "3.2.0",
```

##### Note:

1. I tried to use this code yesterday in another app. The app was fine (everything was running as I want). I don't know why this time the code was not running as the previous app.
2. If this question is not clear enough, please let me know. I will update is as soon as possible.

##### Update:

1. In the previous app (yesterday app), if I clicked the logout button, the app would refresh one time (from keycloak) and the keycloak login page appeared.
2. In this app (today app), if I clicked the logout button, the app would refresh three times (from keycloak), the keycloak recognized the user is authenticated (`keycloackValue` and `authenticated` are `not null` and `true`), and the keycloak login page didn't appeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying and debugging for some days, finally I found the solution.

Just comment or remove `checkLoginIframe: false` in `KeycloackContext.js`. It fix the logout problem.

Keycloack.js

```js
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'

// KEYCLOACK
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js'

const KeycloackContext = createContext()

const KeycloackContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [ keycloackValue, setKeycloackValue ] = useState(null)
    const [ authenticated, setAuthenticated ] = useState(false)

    const setKeycloack = () => {
        const keycloak = Keycloak({
            realm: process.env.REACT_APP_WULING_KEYCLOAK_REALM,
            url: process.env.REACT_APP_WULING_KEYCLOAK_URL,
            clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_WULING_KEYCLOAK_CLIENTID,
        })

        keycloak.init({
            onLoad: 'login-required', 
            // checkLoginIframe: false, // remove checkLoginIframe here
        }).then(authenticated => {
            setKeycloackValue(keycloak)
            setAuthenticated(authenticated)
        })
    }

    const logout = () => {
        setKeycloack(null)
        setAuthenticated(false)
        keycloackValue.logout()
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setKeycloack()
    }, [])

    return (
        <KeycloackContext.Provider
            value={{
                keycloackValue,
                authenticated,
                logout
            }}
        >
            {props['children']}
        </KeycloackContext.Provider>
    )
}

export { KeycloackContextProvider, KeycloackContext }
```